# Dos proyectos android en uno: Conflictos de ID

Tags: android

Tengo una solución con dos proyectos android.

Uno, es un proyecto normal (Que puede ser compilado) pero tengo intención de utilizarlo como libreria. Vamos a llamarlo "PLIB".

Otro, es una aplicación normal, que, referencia a este proyecto libreria para implementar sus clases, funciones y recursos. Lo llamare "PAPP".

Hasta aquí todo bien.

El problema es que PLIB, tiene un layout "Library.axml" que se corresponde al ID "2130903040" en el Resource.designer.cs

Cuando compilo el proyecto "PAPP" este, tiene un layout "Main.axml" que corresponde también al ID "2130903040".

Entonces, cuando el código de PLIB intenta utilizar el recurso "Resource.Layout.Library" como tiene el mismo ID "2130903040", en lugar de encontrar a "Library.axml" encuentra "Main.axml".

¿Como podría forzar a que las ID's de los recursos ambos proyectos no coincidan nunca y así funcione?

Comment: Omendoza, realiza un  Build > Clean Project seguramente tienes otro conflicto el cual impide se genere nuevamente el archivo R.java, revisa mi respuesta.

Answer (score 0):

Los recursos de PAPP siempre tendrán prioridad sobre los de PLIB, por tanto, te recomiendo cambiar los identificadores de los recursos con un prefijo, algo como "PLIB_nombre_de_tu_recurso"

Comment: El nombre no es el problema, es el ID numérico que le asigna el appt a los nombres

Answer (score 0):

Lo que comentas es cierto, se generan dos ids similar cuando existen dos recursos con el mismo nombre, lo cual se puede ver dentro de los archivos `R.java` de los proyectos.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Pero es importante comentar que esto no genera ningún tipo de conflicto, el recurso que carga la aplicación sería por prioridad el que carga la aplicación.

En el caso que mencionas son dos recursos diferentes por lo cual debería generar dos id diferentes.

Te aconsejo realices un `Build` > `Clean Project` y compila nuevamente tu proyecto, debe generar un id diferente dentro de `R.java` para cada recurso ya que tu aplicación y tu librería al compilar son considerados como un solo proyecto.

En ocasiones vemos que no cambian los id pero eso puede ser causado por otro factor como tener un problema con algún recurso, te doy unos tips:

- El nombre de algún recurso contiene una letra mayúscula, asegura que los nombres de los recursos se especifican en minúsculas.
- Los recursos .xml hacen referencia a un recurso que no existe.

Uno de los proyectos debe estar definido como librería, dependiente del proyecto principal. Si son dos proyectos diferentes, se tendría que renombrar el recurso en alguno de los 2

Comment: appt les asigna el mismo ID, y sí crea conflico.

Comment: ´la única manera de no crear conflico, la única manera de evitarlo es como tu dices que uno de los proyectos sea "library" por que así el appt realmente le asigna otro prefijo numérico.

La pregunta es, ¿Puedo hacerlo sin marcar el proyecto como library? quisiera que este también se pueda compilar.

Comment: @OMendoza, gracias por la aclaración, como menciono en la respuesta uno de los proyectos debe estar definido como librería, dependiente del proyecto principal. Si son dos proyectos diferentes tendrías que renombrar el recurso en alguno de los 2!.

Comment: Esa es precisamente la cuestión, como renombrar los recursos. Pero ojo, no como renombrarlos internamente (nombre de la id) sino, como renombrar el código numérico que le asigna a los recursos el appt para que no coincidan o forzarle a que, al compilar, cambie el prefijo sin necesidad de marcar el proyecto como librería.